# How to get the SNR and the SNIR values when a packet is received in the MAC layer also the network layer

Tags: omnet++, inet

By the Omnet++ 6 and then Inet 4.4 framework:

I have a WiFi network that includes some multi-radio multi-interface nodes,

1. How can I get or calculate the SNR and the SNIR values when receiving a packet at the MAC layer of the receiver node? Should the amount of the SNR and the SNIR be calculated by each radio interface that received the packet?
2. How about in the network layer and the upper layers?

Please include the necessary code in addition to the explanation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every packet received by MAC should contain `SnirInd` tag. According to [the description of this tag](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet-SnirInd.html):

> This indication specifies the signal to noise ratio that was detected during receiving the packet. It may be present on a packet from the phyiscal layer to the application.

In order to obtain that tag one may use that piece of code:

```
if (packet->findTag<SnirInd>()) {
   auto snirIndTag = packet->getTag<SnirInd>();
   double snirMin = snirIndTag->getMinimumSnir();
   double snirMax = snirIndTag->getMaximumSnir();
   double snirAvg = snirIndTag->getAverageSnir();
   EV_INFO << "SNIR min=" << snirMin << ", SNIR max=" << snirMax <<
              ", SNIR avg=" << snirAvg << endl;
}
```

The `SnirInd` is present in a packet during passing it to the upper layers therefore the same piece of code may be used in the network layer.

Comment: If I want to use the code at handleMessage(cMessage *msg) function, the "error: expected expression" error is raised in compile time if I use the msg variable instead of the packet type variable, because packet type is not applied in the arguments function.

Comment: You have to cast an object `cMessage` to `Packet`.